# Star before and after variables in c# documentation

Tags: c#, pointers

The following code, what are the '*' doing?

```
for (Char* ptr1 = (Char*)bstr1.ToPointer(), ptr2 = (Char*)bstr2.ToPointer();
                    *ptr1 != 0 && *ptr2 != 0;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types

Comment: Questions about documentation of any software or library (even windows-system) is considdered off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are unsafe pointers. Look for C# pointers, unsafe C# and similar. Like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types

That code, if it is

```
for (Char* ptr1 = (Char*)bstr1.ToPointer(), ptr2 = (Char*)bstr2.ToPointer();
                *ptr1 != 0 && *ptr2 != 0;
                ptr1 = IntPtr.Add(ptr1, 1), ptr2 = IntPtr.Add(ptr2, 1))
```

(note that the part of the code that increments the `ptr1` and `ptr2` could be a little different. Sadly there is no `++` operator for `IntPtr`)

cycles the characters cointained in the `bstr1` and `bstr2` until one of them is `'\0'`. Given the name, `bstr1` and `bstr2` are probably `BSTR` (Windows unicode strings used in COM programming)

You have that `*ptr1` is the `char` contained in the memory location "pointed" by `ptr1`.

Answer (score 0):

These are pointers. Normally, basic variables (like char, int, float, ...) are passed as values. Which means that if you pass that variable into a method and change the value inside that method, tha variable in the callers context won't be changed at all. Complex tapes (classes) are passed as reference. You change them in the called method and they also change in the caller. With pointers you can pass basic variables references and hence change them in the called method and they also change in the caller. You can also do a bunch of other stuff with pointer. They are a complex construct. I wouldn't recommend to work with them in C#.

Comment: Slight addition: actually neither reference- nor value-types are passed by reference unless you use `ref` on the parameter in your method. The actual reference to your instance is passed by value which means you can´t re-assign another instance to that one passed to the method and expect the calling code to have the new instance also. Of course you can change the members of the instance *referenced* by the parameter (which is itself passed by value).